# VB.Net / JSON - Deserializing

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I've been racking my brain for the past few hours.

I found that you can serialize the data and as such save the hassle of creating endlessly long `.split` commands for each of the seperate JSON values. So I've followed what a lot of people on SO and all over the web have done, by creating a JsonHelper class to Serialize and Deserialize the JSON that is passed from an ASP.net page.

**This is my class:**

```
Public Class NewTaskOb
    Public Property Department As Integer
    Public Property Type As Integer
    Public Property AssignedTo As Integer
    Public Property Priority As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property JobCode As Integer
    Public Property ParentTask As String
    Public Property DueDate As Date
    Public Property Scope As String
    Public Property Comment As String
    Public Property BudgetString As String
End Class
```

**Then I have this:**

```
<WebMethod()> Public Shared Function NewTaskRequest(task As String) As String

    Dim newTask As NewTaskOb = DeserializeJSON.JsonDeserialize(Of NewTaskOb)(task)
```

My JSON is valid according to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), but when I pass the values through, I check by putting a breaker on the `Dim newTask` line, and when I hover my mouse over it, it says each of the values is empty (Department = 0, Type = 0, etc.) when, on the form, I am submitting values.

I have tried by using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, `JsonHelper`, and `JavaScriptSerializer`. Please note, I do not want to import another reference (i.e `Newtonsoft.Json`, or anything similar). I want to get this done using the aforementioned functions.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Edit (adding in the JSON string itself):**

```
{
"NewTask": {
    "Department": "-1",
    "Type": "0",
    "AssignedTo": "0",
    "Priority": "-1",
    "Title": "",
    "JobCode": "-",
    "ParentTask": "-",
    "DueDate": "",
    "Scope": "",
    "Comment": "",
    "BudgetString": ""
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

While messing around with the code, I went back to the `JavaScriptSerializer` and found if I put `Dim data = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(task)` in place of `Dim data = jss.Deserialize(Of NewTaskOb)(task)`, then it shows up while stepping through that there is a dictionary in the data, that has the fields with the data.

[Dictionary showing JSON correctly http://imageshack.com/a/img401/1174/a9ju.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img401/1174/a9ju.png)

Any idea how I can extract these into the class variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like your class definition doesn't suits the JSON string. Could you post sample JSON string that can demonstrates the problem (still outputting empty properties when deserialized to `NewTaskOb`)

Comment: Im currently out of work until tomorrow but once I get into the office I will amend my post with the JSON string. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Okay, so here are the two different scenarios. If I put `Dim taskData As NewTaskOb = jss.Deserialize(Of NewTaskOb)(task)`, it comes up with an error of not being able to convert a string to int - because all the values are empty values. If I put `Dim taskData = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(task)` I get what is seen on the screenshot, and it goes through to an exception that says `Public member 'Department' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' not found.`

Comment: Also, In my JSON I changed the Budget tag to BudgetString, as is in the NewTaskOb Class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was testing your program on my system and noticed that it has Dictionary"2. Imagining what it could possibly mean, I had the idea that 2 could mean there is a dictionary nested within a dictionary - which could explain why you couldn't retrieve the values. So I edited away, and ended up with this line - `Dim taskData = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of Object, Object))(task)`. Now, when I run it I have put in `Dim taskValues = taskData.Values`, and I can reference each of the values using their respective index positions...

i.e taskValues(0) = Department, taskValues(1) = Type, etc.

Also, I removed the line where you were inserting the data into a Data Transfer Object, thus eliminating the `"NewTask":` nesting within the JSON, resulting in this JSON:

```
{
"Department": "-1",
"Type": "0",
"AssignedTo": "0",
"Priority": "-1",
"Title": "",
"JobCode": "-",
"ParentTask": "-",
"DueDate": "",
"Scope": "",
"Comment": "",
"BudgetString": ""
}
```

Comment: Just tested this out, works perfectly for what I need it to do. Thanks!